# How to set google maps to mobile/retina mode (?) - illegible place labels

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, mobile

When I view the map I've embedded on mobile, the place labels are illegible and the map appears much more zoomed out than it does on maps.google.co.uk.  I checked the map on airbnb.com to compare, and they don't seem to have the problem either.  What am I doing wrong?

**Note - the fact that my test map is physically smaller isn't related; I've tried it with a full-page map and the text and other map controls are still as small and illegible as here.**

Here is my test page:

[image]

Here is google:

[image]

Here is my source:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <style>#map { width: 500px; height: 500px }</style>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&libraries=places,geometry&key=[my api key]"></script>
    <script>var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { center: { lat: 53, lng: 1 }, zoom: 11 });</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your style is forcing your map to be 500x500 pixels. Try changing it to `#map { width: 100%; height: 100% }`

Comment: @George see my edit - Note - the fact that my test map is physically smaller isn't related, I've tried it with a full-page map and the text and other map controls are still as small and illegible as here.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I see the problem now. Can you add `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">` into the head element

Comment: Ah, that fixes it, thanks!  And airbnb does have that tag, so I'm guessing that's how they do it as well.  Will have to do some reading up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the issue is with the buttons on the map appearing to be too small when on small devices, the issue is because of how the pixel are rendered on the viewport have a look at the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&libraries=places,geometry&key=AIzaSyCp5RzbQjgID4oHJYe6VRGhKGXpQTGtCmw"></script>
    <script>
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: {
                lat: 53,
                lng: 1
            },
            zoom: 11
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```